# What are the commands to configure static routes using next-hop IP addresses?

Tags: cisco, router, ip-address, next-hop, static

[image]

Given the network topology above and that X in all subnets should be replaced with 1.

What are the commands to configure static routes using the next-hop IP addresses on r1 and r2, given that you are at the global configuration mode on the routers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On R1:

```
ip route 10.1.3.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.2.2
```

On R2:

```
ip route 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.1.2.1
```